# How do I use "KaiTi" font with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, fontspec, cjk, chinese

I'm currently using luatexja-fontspec to input chinese into my LaTeX document but it show this error:

```
The font "KaiTi" cannot be found.
```

How do I use this font or another similar font to it?

I am using chinese for a small title not a whole book so I don't really need to have ctex.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be KaiTi, or will some other Chinese font do as well?

Comment: You probably need the full name, such as `STKaitiSC-Regular`

Comment: I need some kind of Kai chinese font (Regular Script)

Comment: I'm using Overleaf by the way.

Comment: The font names that you can use for Chinese fonts in Overleaf are listed here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese

Comment: If you're on macOS, then try running `tlmgr conf texmf OSFONTDIR /System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_Font6`. `sudo` might be required. The `<n>` in directory name `com_apple_MobileAsset_Font<n>` may change in different versions of macOS. Check [this article](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/85628525) (in Chinese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Overleaf, so you can't find `KaiTi`, you might need `FandolKai`.

```tex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont{FandolKai}
\begin{document}
  测试
\end{document}
```

You can also choose one of the [Chinese fonts supported by Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese).